# Without built-in functions how to find differences in two arrays

Tags: php

I have to find the `difference` for both array, i have tried but i am not getting my expected.can you please help here.

```
<?php

    $firstArray = array(3,4,5,6);
    $secondArray = array(4, 5);
    
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach($firstArray as $firstArrayItem) {
        foreach($secondArray as $secondArrayItem) {
            if($firstArrayItem != $secondArrayItem) {
                $outputArray[] = $firstArrayItem;
            }
        }
        
    }
    print_r($outputArray);
```

> Expected output

```
[3,6]
```

**Note: we should not use PHP inbuild functions.**

Comment: Why you do not want to use built in function?

Comment: Cause it's a (school) assignment

Comment: Currently you're just testing two random items of each array against each other, and if they don't happen to be the same, you append them to the output array. *Of course* that's not the expected result. On the first try, you're comparing `3` and `4`. Yeah, they're not equal, so you append the value to the output. — You only want to append if *none* of the items in the second array are equal to the first. I.e. if you have reached the end of the inner loop without encountering a match.

Comment: Can there be duplicates in either array? BTW, you are using an inbuilt function: `print_r()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Use a boolean value to check it:

```
<?php

$firstArray = array(3,4,5,6);
$secondArray = array(4, 5);

$outputArray = array();

foreach($firstArray as $firstArrayItem) {
$found = false;
    foreach($secondArray as $secondArrayItem) {
        if($firstArrayItem == $secondArrayItem) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    
    if($found == false){
        $outputArray[] = $firstArrayItem;
    }
    
}
print_r($outputArray);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/8CuS8

b) Another way using `for()` loop: https://3v4l.org/9JZrW

Comment: Shouldn't the result be the same when you swap the input arrays?

Comment: @trincot yes, is there any issue?

Comment: If I run the first solution with `$firstArray = [4, 5]` and `$secondArray = [3,4,5,6]` (so the input arrays are swapped) then the output is different (`[]`).

Comment: @trincot  https://3v4l.org/phiKD . means Op want the same like array_diff

Comment: When I run that link, the output is `[]`, which is not the same as `[3, 6]` which you get for the original input.... I would think that the *difference* between two arrays should not depend on which array you provide first.

Comment: @trincot  pls check https://3v4l.org/ZptQC . I hope you will get what I am trying to say and Op seems like want the same. rest OP will come back in case he will found any issue.

Comment: I checked that, and it shows what I expressed in my first comment to which you answered "Yes", but the output clearly confirms that it is "No".

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstArray = array(3,4,5,6);
$secondArray = array(4, 5, 7);

$outputArray = diffArray($firstArray, $secondArray);
$outputArray = diffArray($secondArray, $firstArray, $outputArray);

function diffArray($arr1, $arr2, $result = array()) {
    foreach($arr1 as $arr11) {
        $isExist = false;
        foreach($arr2 as $arr22) {
            if($arr11 === $arr22) {
                $isExist = true;
            }
        }
        if(!$isExist) $result[] = $arr11;
        
    }
    return $result;
}
print_r($outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not give a different result when the input arrays as swapped.

So it will give the same result for this:

```
$firstArray = array(3, 4, 5, 6);
$secondArray = array(4, 5);
```

as for this:

```
$firstArray = array(4, 5);
$secondArray = array(3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Also, it will deal with duplicate values as follows:

```
$firstArray = array(4, 4, 4);
$secondArray = array(3, 4, 6);
```

for which I would expect the output to be:

```
array(3, 4, 4, 6)  // Only one 4 is common and should be excluded.
```

The code for having this behaviour could be (without inbuilt functions except for `print_r`):

```
$assoc = [];
foreach($firstArray as $value) {
    $assoc[$value][] = 1;
}
foreach($secondArray as $value) {
    $assoc[$value][] = -1;
}
foreach($assoc as $value => $list) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($list as $delta) $count += $delta;
    for($i = $count > 0 ? $count : -$count; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```